# How to provide a type hint to a method parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to construct an object literal to pass as an argument to a method and want to make sure it conforms to a particular interface. How can I do that without first creating a temporary variable of that type?

```
interface IPoint {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

// A function I'm given that I can't change
function doSomething(obj: any) { }

function tryToUseDoSomethingSafely() {
    // I'm making sure that the call to doSomething takes a proper IPoint.
    // This does what I want. I'll get a compile error if I forget the x
    // or y components.
    let point: IPoint = { x: 1, y: 2 };
    doSomething(point);

    // How can I do the above WITHOUT creating the temporarily variable?
    // I want something like this where I'd get a compile error message if
    // the parameter is not a proper point; this won't compile.
    doSomething({ x: 1, y: 2 } : IPoint);
}
```

Comment: Where `doSomething` defined and how do you import it?

Comment: its just in a library i use. i suppose i could create a wrapper function for it that takes a specific type, but it seems like there should be a way to pass in an object literal and indicate "this must be an object of type X" without first assigning it to a variable.

Comment: So you should be able to augment library definitions. Have a look at [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

Comment: I will look at that. However I can't believe there isn't a simple way to do what I want here. Suppose you have an array of IPoint and you want to map each one to a point where the x and y are swapped. You can certainly construct a new IPoint in the mapping lambda / arrow function with an object literal BUT there is no way to get intellisense for help with the properties and when you're done you can't be confident it is a proper IPoint.

Answer (score 0):

with type `any` for parameter you can pass everything you want but in your method if you want property `x` or `y` of your given parameter should have it,or you can check if `x` or `y` exists to use or not, and if your point sometimes can be without `x` or `y`, you can define your interface this way:

```
interface IPoint {
    x?: number;
    y?: number;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand my question. I want to ensure that an object literal has ALL the properties of the specified interface before it gets passed to a function that takes an any.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good solution here. Best I came up with is building my own function `exact<T>(T item) { return item; }` and use that anywhere I want to ensure an object literal with a guaranteed type. Related issue on TypeScript design site: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481#issuecomment-386061556